# API: Autosubmitting urls without required user_id gives OK

Tags: flattr

I autosubmitted an url through the flattr api with the url posted to /rest/v2/flattr, but without the user_id query parameter. The submit went through just fine but now there is no owner for the thing: see https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things/504370.

Well, problem is, it cant get flattred and I cannot assign myself as the owner, and it's for my [node-flattr](https://github.com/antics/node-flattr) project page on github. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit things without a user. We find the owner and then set the correct user id. Try to connect your flattr account with your github account. This will move the thing over to you.